Large data not caching. Is there limit for fastcgi cache?
I'm using Nginx fastcgi cache with mostly default settings.
Some URLs seem not to cache. It appears this may be related to the response size. Responses over about 5MB don't go into the cache. I can't find anything else to differentiate successful cached responses from unsuccessful ones.
Is there a ceiling? If so, what directives is it based on?
The only non-default settings I've enabled are as follows:
fastcgi_cache_path /foo keys_zone=foo:100m inactive=1d use_temp_path=off max_size=1g min_free=500m;

fastcgi_cache_key  $request_method:$request_uri:$http_authorization;
fastcgi_cache_lock on;
fastcgi_cache_revalidate on;
fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;

Everything else is default.
